# bxslider only working on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I use bxslider, but when I enter the site it keeps loading and the console tells me:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.indexOf')
```

If i refresh it works fine.

I tried it with and without document ready, in the header and in the footer. But nothing seems to work.

```
$( window ).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 2,
      maxSlides: 4,
      slideWidth: 320,
      slideMargin: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: element with this 'bxslider' class exist in your dom?

Comment: instead of `$( window ).ready`, use either `$( window ).load`, or `$( document ).ready`.